# How to deal with suggested edits that get approve but imho violate rule

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, rollbacks, review-abuse

I was reviewing suggested edit when it got approved. When looking at the post it was very clear to me that edit was invalid because someone other than OP was trying to "improve" the answer.

Can someone let me know if I was right to roll it back or am I missing something here. If you look at the comments on the answer the user who suggested an edit clearly disagrees with me.

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/22864835/revisions

Also it is possible to see who Approved the edit?

Comment: if you click word [suggested](http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/1318022) in the revisions history you refer, near rev 4, you will find details of who approved. At the page that opens, you may also click word "more" to find more details about users who suggested and reviewed the edit

Comment: I had no idea about that shortcut that is really helpful, looks like first time 2 people rejected it and second time 1 person rejected it.

Comment: someone other than the OP improving isn't violating any rules, it's a feature for a reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rule against editing code isn't violated in this case as far as I can tell from a quick glance. The edit adds a diff between the code in the question and the fixed code in the self-answer, which looks pretty useful to me. This only makes it easier to see what the user actually did, it doesn't fundamentally change the code.

In general, never get into an edit war with a user. Don't roll back a second time, simply flag for a moderator if you think the edit is harmful. A regular user doesn't have the necessary tools to deal with this situations.

Comment: But it clearly adds something that was not there. That is why I left the comment for user to put it into his own answer. I will stick to advice to flag it for moderator after first roll-back.

Comment: The edit does not add anything really new, it is a diff between the code in the question (from the same author) and the code in the answer. The diff is more readable, which is an improvement over the large code dump. This is really much closer to formatting an answer than changing the code in an answer.